# Could you give me a usage for array_pad in PHP?

Tags: php

I see a function in PHP : [array_pad()](http://php.net/array_pad)

I never use it.

Comment: Please read the manual before asking. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be used when an array is required to contain a minimum number of elements, but one is not certain that there are enough, e.g. the top 10 high scores on a game that has only had 5 people play thus far.

Answer (score 5):

While I've also never used it, the [PHP manual page for the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) has a few use cases and examples.

Answer (score 1):

The [array_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pad.php) function inserts a specified number of elements, with a specified value, to an array.

For example :

```
<?php
$demo = array("Dog","Cat");
print_r(array_pad($demo,5,0));
?>
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
Array ( [0] => Dog [1] => Cat [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 )
```